# mysql.connector update statement using dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, connection

I'm trying to update a mysql table using a dataframe id column (same id as in database table) and the corresponding values of another column (e.g. "text"), but I'm not able to pass through the prepared statement the correct columns (I tried different methods but it just throws me warnings).
Anyone has an idea of how to solve this? I'm sure it's quite easy.

I have opened a connection, and the query to insert is

```
query = """ UPDATE user
                SET extra = ?
                WHERE id = ? """
```

while the dataframe is like this:

```
data= pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2,3], 'text': ["yes", "no", "maybe"]})
```

However I can't pass the query and the data in the execute statement

```
cursor.execute(query, data)
```

What's the correct way of passing the columns?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could pass a pandas dataframe as the "data" to the query placeholder directly. I would recommend using a for loop to do this job.

```
data = {'id': [1, 2,3], 'text': ["yes", "no", "maybe"]}

query = """
  UPDATE user
  SET extra = '{}'
  WHERE id = {}
"""

for i in range(3):
  cursor.execute(query.format(data['text'][i], data['id'][i]))
```

Edited:

As I am agnostic of your Python version. Here is another form of the solution you may have a try.

```
data = {'id': [1, 2,3], 'text': ["yes", "no", "maybe"]}

query = """
  UPDATE user
  SET extra = %s
  WHERE id = %s
"""

for i in range(3):
  cursor.execute(query, (data['text'][i], data['id'][i]))
```

Comment: I know my solution might not be the perfect one, but I'm trying to help people here. If you believe my solution doesn't work or there are any problems, could you please comment on my answer in order to improve it? I don't think downvoting without any comments is very polite here.

Comment: I'm not the one that downvoted. Anyway, the solution doesn't work: mine is closer to the probable correct way, as per mysql.connector library information. However, the point is, as you wrote, to pass a pandas dataframe to the execute command.

Comment: @ALEX, thanks for your feedback. I don't think mysql.connector can make use Pandas DataFrame directly. You can use `sqlalchemy` which is always my favourite. `mysql.connector` is a bit low-level.